# Tabs Jquery ultima deixou de funcionar

Tags: php, jquery

```
 <div id="tabs">
 <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Informação</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Trabalhadores</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Equipamentos</a></li>

</ul>
```

Codigo:

```
   echo '<div id="tabs-3">
  <p><b> Maquina Electrosoldadura (1)</b></p>
       <p>Maquina Electrosoldadura Numero: '.$exibe["MaquinaNumero1"].'</p>
       <p>Maquina Electrosoldadura Validade:';
            if ($exibe['MaquinaValidade1']) { 
            if (strtotime($exibe['MaquinaValidade1']) < time()) 
            {
            echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['MaquinaValidade1'].'</span>';
            } else {
            echo $exibe['MaquinaValidade1'];
            }
            } else { 
            echo 'N/D';
            }
            echo '</p>
        <p>Maquina Electrosoldadura Modulo: '.$exibe["MaquinaModulo1"].'</p>    
       <p>Maquina Electrosoldadura Anexo: <a href="MostrarMaquina1.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">Ver PDF </a></p>

    <p><b> Maquina Electrosoldadura (2)</b></p>
       <p>Maquina Electrosoldadura Numero: '.$exibe["MaquinaNumero2"].'</p>
       <p>Maquina Electrosoldadura Validade:';
            if ($exibe['MaquinaValidade2']) { 
            if (strtotime($exibe['MaquinaValidade2']) < time()) 
            {
            echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['MaquinaValidade2'].'</span>';
            } else {
            echo $exibe['MaquinaValidade2'];
            }
            } else { 
            echo 'N/D';
            }
            echo '</p>
        <p>Maquina Electrosoldadura Modulo: '.$exibe["MaquinaModulo2"].'</p>    
       <p>Maquina Electrosoldadura Anexo: <a href="MostrarMaquina2.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">Ver PDF </a></p>


       <p><b> Maquina Electrosoldadura (3)</b></p>
       <p>Maquina Electrosoldadura Numero: '.$exibe["MaquinaNumero3"].'</p>
       <p>Maquina Electrosoldadura Validade:';
            if ($exibe['MaquinaValidade3']) { 
            if (strtotime($exibe['MaquinaValidade3']) < time()) 
            {
            echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['MaquinaValidade3'].'</span>';
            } else {
            echo $exibe['MaquinaValidade3'];
            }
            } else { 
            echo 'N/D';
            }
            echo '</p>';
        echo '<p>Maquina Electrosoldadura Modulo: '.$exibe["MaquinaModulo3"].'</p>  
       <p>Maquina Electrosoldadura Anexo: <a href="MostrarMaquina3.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">Ver PDF </a></p>

       <p><b> Maquina Topo-a-Topo:</b></p>
       <p>Maquina Topo-a-Topo Numero: '.$exibe["MaquinaTopoNumero"].'</p>
       <p>Maquina Topo-a-Topo Validade:';
            if ($exibe['MaquinaTopoValidade']) { 
            if (strtotime($exibe['MaquinaTopoValidade']) < time()) 
            {
            echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['MaquinaTopoValidade'].'</span>';
            } else {
            echo $exibe['MaquinaTopoValidade'];
            }
            } else { 
            echo 'N/D';
            }
         echo '</p><p>Maquina Topo-a-Topo Anexo: <a href="MaquinaTopoMaquina.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">Ver PDF </a></p>

 </div>';



  }     

?>
```

Neste codigo a tabs-3 deixou de funcionar assim de repente. Aparece completamente em branco

Comment: Alguns compiladores não gostam de espaços junto a concatenações. Já experimentou remover os espaços em branco aqui: `id=' . $exibe['id'] . '"` ?

Comment: Sim já experimentei ... E deixou de funcionar assim de repente

Comment: Tirei os espaços e nada..

Comment: Tem algum erro no PHP? como está a fazer debug? junte isto à página PHP se não tiver já: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors", 1); `

Comment: Consegui perceber qual era o problema aqui?

Comment: Eu acho que o problema é a poluição do código HTML e PHP misturado com quebras de linha, já tive este problema, no manual diz que não há algum, mas eu pessoalmente já tive.

Comment: Misturar PHP+HTML como se não houvesse amanhã, uma das piores práticas na minha opinião.

Answer (score -1):

Gera a página HTML desse trecho e usa um validador, ex. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input. Daí ele pode mostrar se o erro está na geração do código HTML.